# Armature Fingertips Not Following Bone

Tags: animation, armature, rigging

I've been working with making a rig for about 2 hours, now, but just can't get past one issue. I had several issues with my rig, but then I used an automatic deform instead of an empty group and assigning all the vertex manually.

The only issue I can find now, it that when I move the fingertip bones, the fingertip don't follow the bones correctly. If I move the whole arm, or the forearm or hand, the fingertips move correctly with the whole arm, but moving the actual fingertip bones doesn't work correctly.

I'm guessing it has something to do with bone weighting, but I don't know what to adjust.

Here is a picture of the finger before moving the bone:
[image: Normal Bone]

And here is one after moving the bone:
[image: Moved Bone]

EDIT:
I  just found out that it only happens with the finger tips on the index fingers, all the other fingers are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend suggested I check if the finger end was connected to any other bone, it was also connected to the middle part of the finger. Fixed that, and now it works fine.