# Part of finger not following bone properly

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image]

Here the tip of the finger is supposed to be where to bone is but instead it is moving very slowly. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: You may need to post the blend file so that we can break it apart.  You can do this using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).  My thought is that another bone is partially controlling the area highlighted red.

Comment: Two remarks : first, the bones are not centered to the mesh, so the rig can not be "efficient" (you said "move very slowly") ; second, your mesh need to be "curvable" so that it can follow the bones movements. But keep on it ! it is a good starting job !

Comment: Also, see [this related question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15270/21825) that is most likely your problem.  (Note, I have not looked at your blend file yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the other bone is also influencing it.
You need to subtract those vertices from the other bone.
[image]